# How Fine-tuned my trained model (bert) on another dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

*** I used a pretrained BertModel to fine-tune model on squadv1 then fine-tune result model to final model.

This how I can load my trined model on squadv1

```
output_dir="mybert_squadv1/checkpoint-60000/"
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(output_dir, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)
```

after I loaded my model on a dataset, I want to fine-tune this model on another dataset. Let say squadv3
Can I do that or not ? if so, how i can do it?

Comment: See https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training

Answer (score 0):

you just get the tokenizer.
After that,you should add your own Neural Networks after that and loss function.
you can see how to train a normal network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).